# Flex items exceed container height when wrapped in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, flexbox

In the current Firefox (50), when the two items in the header wrap below 715px, the lower item extends below the header's height. I have played with the flex shorthand statements of each item, and min-widths, and tried a @media query for a screen with that max-width, and can't get it to stop. The page is [here](http://www.moonwards.com/rotovator.html).

The CSS:

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row-reverse wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  height: 320px;
  padding: 20px 0;
}
.sec1 {
  flex: 4 2 200px;
  min-width: 200px;
  padding-right: 6vw;
  padding-left: 3vw;
  margin-top: 2vw;
  @media only screen and (max-width: 1350px) {
    flex: 6 1 0;
    margin-top: 6vw;
  }
}
.sec2 {
  align-self: center;
  flex: 7 0 250px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  p {
    width: 40%;
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }
}
.accent {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #967832;
  line-height: 24px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 8px solid black;
  padding: 12px;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: stretch;
}
section {
  display: box;
  display: flex;
  padding: 15px;
  flex: 1 0 350px;
  margin-top: 3vw;
  margin-left: 6vw;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="sec1">
    <img src="http://www.moonwards.com/img/MWLogo-for-black-bckgnd.svg" alt="Moonwards" id="logo">
  </div>
  <div class="sec2">
    <p class="accent">What would it really be like
      <br>to live on the Moon?</p>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="container">
  <section>
    <div class="outerDiv">
      <div class="innerDiv intro">
        <h1>Realistic Lunar Colony, Coming Online</h1>
        <p>
          This project is building a series of virtual colonies on the Moon. They will be richly detailed and interactive presentations that are entirely plausible, technically and scientifically. They will examine all the questions, consider all the implications.
          When humanity undertakes ventures on the scale of space settlement, it matters a great deal how many people have given it real thought beforehand. These colonies serve that purpose.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <aside>
  <div class="sideDiv"id="RSS-feed">
      <p id="item2" class="atom"><span class="datetime">Mon, 07 Nov 2016 19:50:00 GMT</span><span class="title"><a href="http://www.moonwards.com/">Lalande map</a></span><span class="description">Kim has finished composing an extremely detailed map of the Lalande crater. It is a huge file, but available at request.</span>
      </p>
  </div>
```

The issue seems to be that Firefox isn't considering the height of the container when wrapping. What is the way to stop the overflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is overly complex. Much of it can be safely removed. Try a process of elimination to pinpoint the problem.

Here's a revised version of your code (tested on Chrome & FF):

```
<header>
  <img id="logo" src="http://www.moonwards.com/img ... svg" alt="Moonwards" id="logo">
  <p id="note">What would it really be like<br> to live on the Moon?</p>
</header>
```

[**revised codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GrNKMv?editors=1100)

Comment: I'll remember that as general practice, but it didn't help in this case. I updated the page with a div of class 'sec1' wrapping the logo, and took that class off the logo. It is doing the same thing.

Comment: Actually, before posting my answer, I wrapped your image in a div, and the layout worked. Meaning, the lower element didn't overflow the header and the layout looked just like in Chrome. That's why I posted this answer.

Comment: Then there must be some other difference between how you are doing it and the live page. The live page isn't working.

Comment: Were you able to resolve the problem? Not much else I can do from this end. After the fix, I'm seeing the same layout in Chrome and FF.

Comment: No. And a similar behavior is on another page, and it is happening in Chrome, too. There is something else going on i don't understand at all. I tried just pushing down the header, but the layout on Chrome and Firefox is completely different, and often ugly depending on the screen width, and every attempt to fix that brings the overlapping problem back. I suppose maybe i should edit the question, but i'm rather lost now.

Comment: Try a process of elimination. That's how I sometimes find a deep-rooted problem in the code.

Comment: I stripped out all the stuff added by Bourbon. I'm writing a CodePen that can maybe help. The header became more convoluted when i couldn't place things. You could well be right, but so far no attempt to cut things down has helped.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133301/discussion-between-kim-holder-and-michael-b).

Comment: The problem was resolved in chat by taking a different tack that considered more than what i asked about. The code was simplified and the proportional sizing i wanted was achieved by making the flex-basis of the items a percentage. A clean, simple solution.